# Retrieving lost data from crashed QGIS

Tags: qgis, error

My problem might be somewhat similar to the following one: [Retrieving lost data from QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80667/retrieving-lost-data-from-qgis). However, I need some further clarifications:

I was working with a project in QGIS. Suddenly, an error message with the title "Krasch dumpad" (Crash dumped) shows up (see pic 1 below). 
[image: First error message]

I then closed everything, restarted my computer and opened up the program again. When I tried to enter/open the same project, I recieved the following error message (see pic 2). The error message says: "error occurred while parsing element on line 1 column 1 for file C:/Users/H..."

[image: Second error message]

Have I lost the project and need to redo all the operations for this project (all of my analysis in QGIS)?

Answer (score 1):

QGIS generates a backup of the project qgs-file with an appended ~. If you delete the corrupt qgs-file and rename the backup myproject.qgs~ to myproject.qgs you should be up and running again. Replace myproject with you own project filename.